# How to snap while beveling an edge

Tags: modeling, mesh, snapping, bevel

In picture 1 I beveled the edge A into a curved one and then added one loopcut aligned with the end of the bevel (red circle).

Then, Pic. 2, I am trying to bevel the second edge in the same way as the first edge. In order to have a vertex to snap to, I had the nice idea of mirroring the first loopcut (arrow a) so that I got the second loopcut (arrow b, cyan dots).

Now, I am still suspended trying to bevel the 2nd edge snapping it onto the cyan circle (cyan dotted loopcut).

Any suggestions?

[image: l]